# PHP: User logged in sessions and cookies

Tags: php, session-state, session-cookies

Sorry for the newbie question! I'm making a small website that allows users to create their own accounts. It's not a banking system, and it's unlikely that someone would want to hack it. That said, I am trying to make it reasonably secure, as there are plenty of bored script kiddies out there.

Could someone describe a basic workflow for a user logging in and having a cookie set that will keep them logged in for 30 days?

At the moment I have the following:

1. Validate and sanitize inputted data.
2. Check supplied credentials against bcrypt hashed password in DB.
3. If correct then call "Login" function.
4. Login function:

   a. Delete any session data from DB with userID (table with two columns: SessionString and UserID).
   b. Add new session data to DB (newy random generated string and UserID).
   c. Write random generated string and UserID to cookie.
   d. Set `$_SESSION("UserID")` with `$userID`.

But although the two cookies are being created and written to, the `$_SESSION("UserID")` remains blank... I'm guessing because I can't write to `$_SESSION` any time I like?

And even once that's fixed, how do I use the data stored in the cookie to log a user in? I'm guessing I don't want to go to the DB on every page load. And it will still require me to create a database object to see if the credentials in the cookie are ok. Is this the right way to this?

Once again, apologies for the newbie question!

---

**UPDATE:**
Yes, I do understand the difference between `$_SESSION` variables and a cookies. I also have `session_start()` at the top of every page (right after `<php` with no blank lines). `$_SESSION("UserID")` just remains blank.

Here's the code from the top of the page:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['initiated'])) {
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['initiated'] = true;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: i am not sure if you have done this.. but have you done setcookie at all? if yes, then using $_COOKIE you can access the info and do the login part. while doing setcookie you can set the expiry to 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there is an important difference between a session and a cookie. When you use the `$_SESSION[".."]` you are creating a session (which lives on the server, compared to a cookie which lives on the client), even though the browser uses a cookie to keep track of the session id. To create a cookie you would use the [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) method.

That said, I would recommend you to read through [this article](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Creating-a-Secure-PHP-Login-Script/) which is a step-by-step guide on how to create a secure login script, with persistence using a cookie for a "Remember me"-feature. Describe how to do it in detail would be to extensive for an SO answer im afraid.

**Side note:**

To be able to write to the session, you might have to call `session_start();` prior to getting or setting a session variable using `$_SESSION[".."]`.

Comment: I've updated my original question. I already have `session_start()` at the top, but for some reason certain session variables aren't being set. Argh.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Since we don't see that part of the code in the question it is a bit hard solve, but if some session-variables get set and others don't, my first guess would be that you misspell the session variable name `UserID` somewhere, like `userId` or `UserId` or something like that - since the variable name is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yep, it's an odd one, but it's in a different part of the code. I'll keep digging. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you write a custom session handler that has your session-files stored in the db? I guess you don't.

If you want to use `$_SESSION` you have to also do `session_start()`. When using PHP sessions the cookie to identify the user will be set for you. You will also get session files created in your /tmp directory. That's the location your variables and anything you assign to `$_SESSION` will be stored.

Unless you define a custom session handler, that will manage the location of the session files, you won't need to query your database. Just save the users credentials in `$_SESSION`.

[See this Tutorial on how to use PHP sessions.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

PS: You access arrays like this: `$_SESSION["UserID"]`, not with `()`.

Answer (score 1):

you might want want to look at this article in which i have already discussed about various types of session hijacking and how you could avoid it.

[session security in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233714/session-security-in-php/7233879#7233879)